# Php Api Client Authorization Bearer

Tags: php

I am using the following function to call API Service that uses Authorization Bearer for authentication. I am getting Authentication Failed.

```
function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Authorization: Bearer a9esthaVUjOuvzTCSTXsJUCK0lCMCk");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    echo $result;

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It had to be

```
array('authorization: Bearer a9esthaVUjOuvzTCSTXsJUCK0lCMCk')
```